# Getting form variables data into twig templates

Tags: 8, forms

I want to pass an array and a form to a template file, using this code.

```php
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['job_locations'] = $job_locations;
  $form['#theme'] = 'search_form';
  $form['#method'] = 'get';
  // Omissis
  return  $form;
}
```

The value of `$job_locations` is the following.

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [city] => Singapore
    [count] => 5
  )
  [1] => Array(
    [city] => Toronto
    [count] => 3
  )
)
```

The content of the template file is the following.

```
{% for location in form.job_locations %}
  {% if location.city  %}
    <li data-original-index="0">
      <a tabindex="0" class="location-list-item" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
        <span class="text">{{ location.city }}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Everything is shown correctly, but the code I am using causes these errors.

> User error: "count" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children()
> User error: "city" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children()

How can I avoid to get these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three possible solutions:

1. Valid render array

   You get a valid render array by putting the content of `city` and `count` in `#markup` elements:

   ```
     'city' => [
       '#markup' => 'Singapore',
   ```
2. Form variable with a `#`

   Or start the variable name with a hash, so that it is no longer
   considered to be a form element which needs to be rendered:

   ```
   $form['#job_locations'] = ...
   ```

   Twig:

   ```
   {% for location in form['#job_locations'] %}
     ...
   {% endfor %}
   ```
3. Separate template

   Or create a custom template
   with a variable for the locations array to theme the list separately from the
   form:

   ```
   $form['job_locations'] = [
     '#theme' => 'job_location_list',
     '#locations' => $job_locations,
   ];
   ```